# Problems with Spanish characters á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, character-encoding

I'm having problems with the text of the  in CodeIgniter with the text that have latin characters.

I write in the inputext: `Solución` and press the button save, but in the database appears: `soluciÃ³n` obviously when I get the data on the website shows: `soluciÃ³n`

I inserted in the database the word `más`, and in the website shows `más`, for that which is not the problem.

I'm using JSF, java, openjpa in Intellij IDEA 12. I'm using MySql, in the sql script says:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `ciclos_calidad` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

I have:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputext value="#{hi.word}/>
    <h:commandbutton actionlistener="#{hi.save()}" value="Save"/>
</h:form>
```

In the java i have:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "hi")
@ViewScoped
public class hi{

   private String word;
   private HiController hiController;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
    ...
   }
   ...
   /*getter and setter*/
   ...
   public void save(){
    hiController.save(word);
   }
}
```

Comment: This data is encoded in UTF-8. You can decode it at runtime or change the default encoding the DBMS will reply you, but how you do that will depend on what database system you are using.

Comment: I'm using MySql, but in the sql script says:

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 'ciclos_calidad' /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;`
in the JSF page have: 
`<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8"  pageEncoding="UTF-8">
    <h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Please show where are your problems: in client side when showing data from database, at server side in application level, when receiving the data from client, at server side in database level, when storing the data...

Comment: It seems everything will work like a charm. At least to your visitors perspective, that are seeing UTF-8 properly. You only have to tell whatever application you are using to inspect the database to do that aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all be sure that the Encoding of your database is UTF-8, and if the problem still exists use one of the following solution:

1- use a web filter to encod your data to UTF-8.the code of web filter:

```
    public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

  @Override
   public void destroy() {

      }
 }
```

and the web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>UTFEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>UTFEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Or

try to put your encoding in the server configuration file itself.For Example in glassfish-web.xml put this line

```
   <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
```